# open new window in php

Tags: php

```
<?php

$_SESSION['dsize'] = $_POST['dsize'];
if ($_SESSION['deadline']=="Urgent" )
{
?>
<script type = "text/javascript">

window.open('https://usd.swreg.org/cgi-bin/s.cgi?s=104597&p=104597-1&v=0&d=0&q=<?php echo $_SESSION['dsize']?>');
</script>
<?php

}
else
{

?>
<script type = "text/javascript">

window.open('https://usd.swreg.org/cgi-bin/s.cgi?s=104597&p=104597-2&v=0&d=0&q=<?php echo $_SESSION['dsize']?>');
</script>
<?php

}

 header('Location: confirmorder.php');

?>
```

if i delete the last header line new window is opening but if i use the header line new window does not open and confirmorder.php is opened.

can anyone tell me how to open new window for checkout and send the user to confirmorder page.

Thanks

Comment: that's easy. open new window in the confirmorder page. or, even better, do not open any windows at all. It's ugly behavior and most browsers will block it anyway.

Comment: Also that's what I call ugly code. 2 **exectly similar** blocks of code with only **one byte** difference.

Comment: i am new and trying to understand how things work. so whats the best way to redirect the user to cart(my teacher wants a new window for that) and in the current window i should display orderconfirmation

Comment: You can't set a header after you have already echoed content in the response body.  HTTP works in two phases - headers then body.  Echoing anything to the body automatically flushes the headers to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use Javascript to redirect the client to the page you want.

At the end of the response, you should do something like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "confirmorder.php"
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: worked beautifully but why wasn't the code i using working...can u please explain what was wrong with it so i don't make the same mistake again

Comment: Well... your code was sending the JS that opens the window to the browser, then, immediately, sending a http redirect. This translates to the browser not even trying to interpret the JS (because HTTP headers, like redirect, take precedence). So.... the browser gets redirected before trying to render / interpret anything.

Comment: Are you really think that this code is sending HTTP header *after* JS?

Comment: can you direct me to a document which i can read and understand what the precedence is when redirecting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually in works I use this code

```
function openNewTap(string $url)
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.open("'.$url.'");';
            echo '</script>';
        }
```